# If I roll $3$ dice, what is the chance that some of them land on one specific number?

Tags: probability, dice

Imagine you're at a friend’s house, and he asks you to choose a number between $1$ and $6$. You then roll $3$ dice.
What would be the probability that one out of these $3$ dice rolls the chosen number?

Comment: It doesn't matter how much times it hits the number.

Comment: Dude come on.... re-write that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $1$ minus the chance that no die hits that number, so that's $$1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3 = 1- \frac{125}{216}= \frac{216}{216}- \frac{125}{216} = \frac{216-125}{216} =\frac{91}{216}\approx42.13\%.$$